# Get collection operation sequence MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-oplog

I need to get sequence of collection operation in runtime by daemon to write it to system similar to message broker. Necessary ability to read history from a specified position

Probably I can solve this problem by reading opLog.

1. Is it the correct solution to use opLog?
2. Does oplog contains records for all db, not slited by collections?

Use MongoDB v4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it the correct solution to use opLog?

The oplog format is internal and designed to support replication. As an internal format, it is subject to change between major server releases and not straightforward to consume.

You should instead use the [Change Streams API](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) which builds on the oplog and allows subscribing to data changes on a collection, database, or deployment level. Unlike direct oplog access, change streams have a documented API, can be limited with access control, can perform some filtering and modification of stream output, and can scale to support replica sets as well as sharded clusters. Change streams can also [be resumed](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#resume-a-change-stream) if interrupted.

> Necessary ability to read history from a specified position

Change streams in MongoDB 4.0+ allow you to specify `startAtOperationTime` to open the cursor at a particular point in time.  If the specified starting point is in the past, it must be in the time range of the oplog.

> Does oplog contains records for all db, not slited by collections?

The oplog is a [capped collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) containing a rolling history of all data changes for a replica set or shard. The capped collection aspect means that the oplog has a limited history window: once the maximum oplog size is reached, the oldest entries are removed to make room for new documents. The `local.oplog.rs` data is not filtered by collection or namespace.

Comment: Can I get change stream cursor from very beginning of oplog in first run, or I can only start from current moment, and then use resume token?

Comment: And will it work correct if my resume token will be too old (out of oplog)?